# Android Cursor Adapter layout issue.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, custom-adapter

In my application I am using Adapter.
I struck at here .
Actually I required to display **xml/filename.xml** into as below.

I want to display like below code.

I already done this manually but is there any method like we call layout.
    `xml >layout> filename.xml` and it display

how to do coding like this into xml file into the res/xml/..?

```
<cursor-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.xmladapters"
      app:uri="content://com.android.contacts/contacts"
      app:selection="has_phone_number=1"
      app:layout="@layout/contact_item">

      <bind app:from="display_name" app:to="@id/name" app:as="string" />
      <bind app:from="starred" app:to="@id/star" app:as="drawable">
            <map app:fromValue="0" app:toValue="@android:drawable/star_big_off" />
            <map app:fromValue="1" app:toValue="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />
      </bind>
      <bind app:from="_id" app:to="@id/name" app:as="com.example.android.xmladapters.ContactPhotoBinder" />

    </cursor-adapter>
```

Comment: why making your life complicated when you can get it done with only few lines of code?

Comment: @Waqas its sometime display error into code..
and I have to go for whole process again.